# How to assign static data into class with list properties in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is my model

```
public class LinkModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubLinkModel> SubLinkName { get; set; }

}

public class SubLinkModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am writing the following code to assign data to LinkModel

```
List<LinkModel> linkModel=new List<LinkModel> ();
linkModel.Add(new LinkModel { Name = "MainLink1", SubLinkName = new List<SubLinkModel> { } });
linkModel.Add(new LinkModel { Name = "MainLink2" });
```

I want to assign data to SubLinkModel also.

Comment: Could you show an example what  you mean? I'm not really sure what you want. You can assign values to SubLinkModel the same way you did with LinkModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it with [Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb384062.aspx) like this:-

```
 List<LinkModel> linkModel = new List<LinkModel>
        {
            new LinkModel { Name = "MainLink1", SubLinkName = new List<SubLinkModel> { new SubLinkModel { Name = "foo" }, new SubLinkModel { Name = "bar" } } },
            new LinkModel { Name = "MainLink2", ...
        };
```

Or if you find this complex then you can create the SubLink collection separately and then add it:-

```
List<SubLinkModel> SubLink1 = new List<SubLinkModel>
                            {
                               new SubLinkModel { Name = "foo1" },
                               new SubLinkModel { Name = "bar1" },
                            };

List<SubLinkModel> SubLink2 = new List<SubLinkModel>
                            {
                               new SubLinkModel { Name = "foo2" },
                               new SubLinkModel { Name = "bar2" },
                            };
```

..and so on.

Finally add it to the main collection:-

```
List<LinkModel> linkModel = new List<LinkModel>
            {
                new LinkModel { Name = "MainLink1", SubLinkName = SubLink1 },
                new LinkModel { Name = "MainLink2", SubLinkName = SubLink2 },
                ..and so on 
            };
```